# Skier, выводиться ошибка типа TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

И снова здравствуйте!
Нашёл другой код, но опять ошибка:

```
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\Skier.py", line 23, in turn
    self.image = pygame.image.load(skier_images(list('D:\My Games\skier_images\self.angle')))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Ошибка в данном коде:

```
#Поворачиваем лыжника
    def turn(self, direction):
        self.angle = self.angle + direction
        if self.angle < -2: self.angle = -2
        if self.angle > 2: self.angle = 2
        center = self.rect.center
        self.image = pygame.image.load(skier_images(list('D:\My Games\skier_images\self.angle')))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        speed = [self.angle, 6 - abs(self.angle) * 2]
        return speed
```

Знатоки! Обращаюсь к вам! Не будьте равнодушными! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Замените `list(...)` на `[...]`. И прочитайте какую-нибудь хорошую книжку и/или возьмите курс по питону, пожалуйста!

Comment: Если задавали вопрос и получили ответ на него, то нужно отметить ответ как решение и, при держание, поставить ему плюс. Иначе после двух- трёх вопросов в которых вы не отметили ответ, вам могут просто перестать отвечать.

Comment: Александр, ответ в комментариях. Ему галку ставить нельзя. А так спасибо

Comment: Сергей, уже читаю:) Спасибо за совет и за помощь